# Replace string from a sentence

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

I have a requirement to replace a string in a sentence. Following is my code

**CASE 1(Working): namesArray have names**

```
var response = "Thank you for your request [VARIABLE]. [VARIABLE] will assit you.";
i = 0; 
namesArray= ['Emmy', 'John']
response.replace(/\[VARIABLE\]/g, str => {
var replace = namesArray[i];
i++;
return replace;
});
Output = Thank you for your request Emmy. John will assist you.
```

Above code is working fine, sometimes the 'namesArray' may have null values in that case output will have white spaces in replaced location(ie 'request .'). How can I remove that white space when replacing an empty value.

**CASE 2(Not working): namesArray  have null values**

```
var response = "Thank you for your request [VARIABLE]. [VARIABLE] will assit you.";
i = 0; 
namesArray = ['', 'John']
response.replace(/\[VARIABLE\]/g, str => {
var replace = namesArray[i];
i++;
return replace;
});

Output = Thank you for your request . John will assist you.
```

**Expected Output = Thank you for your request. John will assist you.**

Comment: If the ith name in the array is empty, replace with an empty string, else replace with the name itself

Comment: Now am replacing with an empty string and getting whitespace in the replaced location ie 'request .'. I would like to remove that white space and show it as 'request.'

Comment: Capture the space after request as well, and then replace accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could match the whitespace preceding `[VARIABLE]` and conditionally substitute it back in:

```js
const response = "Thank you for your request [VARIABLE]. [VARIABLE] will assist you.";
let i = 0;
const namesArray = ['', 'John'];

const result = response.replace(/(\s*)\[VARIABLE\]/g, (m0, spaces) => {
  const replace = namesArray[i++];
  return replace ? spaces + replace : '';
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I don't know where you got the names from. But, from the information you provided. I would prefill namesArray with default values.
for eg. namesArray = ['user', 'agent']
If your source of names replace the user or agent you will see the correct result, if not you will have either user or agent instead of white spaces.

Comment: As per my requirement, I couldn't prefill my names array. I am trying for If no names in the array leave it as blank without a whitespace.